# Browser plugin to suggest words as you type

Tags: browser, plugins, autocomplete

is there any browser plugin (doesn't matter which browser) that can give you a list of word suggestions as you type inside a textarea (e.g. like this one on superuser, or email content area).

For example, you start typing a letter 'a', it pop-ups a list of words starting with 'a', ordered by how frequent you use those words.

Think about those typing aids on smart phones, but this one is for PC browsers.

Best if the list of word suggestions is customizable (i.e. you can add/remove/edit the words)

Thank you

Comment: This question would be more on-topic on Software Recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

[PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) provides the MS Office like Autotext feature in any Windows program, e.g. Internet Explorer, Excel, Database Front Ends, etc.

[The mobile phone text input T9-like predictive text feature](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2010/06/save-time-while-typing-with.html) is present in the [paid versions of the tool](http://www.phraseexpress.com/docs10/09/shop.php).

Answer (score 1):

PhraseExpress also has a so called SmartComplete feature: http://www.phraseexpress.com/smartcomplete.htm

It's free for personal use.